# How to measure the size of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object and I want to know approximately how many bytes it is.  How can I do this?  It doesn't need to be exact. I want a relatively accurate measure so that I can tell how complex it is.

The object is a set of JSON multi-polygons.  I want to know how large they are so I can estimate how long it will take Google Maps API to display them.

In PHP, I'd run serialize() on it and then strlen().

Comment: `strlen(serialize(x))` -> `JSON.stringify(x).length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the size of an object in Javascript, you can convert it to JSON string and find its length

```
JSON.stringify(value).length
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just download this: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

include it and do:

```
json_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(json_data.length);
```

Comment: Unless you need to support ancient browsers, you do not need to include `json2.js`, it is now included into the standard.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this simple way to find object length:**

```
Object.keys(object name).length;
```